# How to make Zoomable grouped bar chart in vega?

Tags: vega

I have several time series and try to plot them with rect mark, and the chart should be able to zoomed in/out;
I did some research and found out that：for band scale it cannot be zoomed; but for quantitative scale, it's really hard to plot bar chart
I managed to acheive it by the following json, still there are two problems:

1. for xOffset，step in range is quite tricky to set, is there a way to set it according to the number of data?
2. the bar width stays the same when zoomed in, is it possible to enlarge the barwidth with zooming?

Json code is as following:

```json
{
  "width": 800,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "contains": "padding"},

"signals": [
    {
      "name": "delta_anchor",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {
        "events": "pointerdown, touchstart",
        "update": "{x: x(), y: y(), extent_x: domain('xscale'), extent_y: domain('yscale')}"
        }
   ]
    },
    {
    "name": "delta",
    "on": [
      {
        "events": [
          {
            "source": "window", "type": "pointermove", "consume": true,
            "between": [{"type": "pointerdown"}, {"source": "window", "type": "pointerup"}]
          },
          {
            "type": "touchmove", "consume": true,
            "filter": "event.touches.length === 1"
          }
        ],
        "update": "{x: delta_anchor.x - x(), y: delta_anchor.y - y()}"
      }
    ]
    },

    {
      "name": "zoom_anchor",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "wheel",
          "update": "{x: invert('x', x()), y: invert('yscale', y())}"
        },
        {
          "events": {"type": "touchstart", "filter": "event.touches.length===2"},
          "update": "{x: (xdom[0] + xdom[1]) / 2, y: (ydom[0] + ydom[1]) / 2}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoom", "value": 1,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "wheel!",
          "force": true,
          "update": "pow(1.01, event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode))"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "dist2"},
          "force": true,
          "update": "dist1 / dist2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dist1", "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"type": "touchstart", "filter": "event.touches.length===2"},
          "update": "pinchDistance(event)"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "dist2"},
          "update": "dist2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dist2", "value": 0,
      "on": [{
        "events": {"type": "touchmove", "consume": true, "filter": "event.touches.length===2"},
        "update": "pinchDistance(event)"
      }]
    },

    {
      "name": "xdom",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": [
            {
            "source": "view",
            "type": "dblclick"
            }
            ],
           "update": "null"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "panLinear(delta_anchor.extent_x, -delta.x / width)"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
          "update": "zoomLinear(domain('xscale'), zoom_anchor.x, zoom)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ydom",
      "on": [
          {
            "events": [
              {
                "source": "view",
                "type": "dblclick"
              },
              {
                "source": "view",
                "type": "touchstart, touchend, touchstart, touchend"
              }
              ],
           "update": "null"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "panLinear(delta_anchor.extent_y, delta.y / height)"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
          "update": "zoomLinear(domain('yscale'), zoom_anchor.y, zoom)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "testSig",
      "on":[
        {
          "events": "mousemove",
          "update": "domain('xscale')"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip_store"
    },
    {
      "name": "stocks",
      "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/data/stocks.csv",
      "format": {"type": "csv", "parse": {"price":"number", "date":"date"}},
      "transform":[
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "year(datum.date) == 2009"
        },
      ]
    },
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "time",
      "domain": {"data": "stocks", 
                 "field": "date"},
      "domainRaw": {"signal": "xdom"},
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "stocks", "field": "price"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "stocks", "field": "symbol"}
    },
    {
      "name": "xOffset",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "stocks", "field": "symbol"},
      "range": {"step": {"signal": "10"}},
      "padding":0.2,
      "align": 0,
    },
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "grid": true},
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale",  "labelOverlap": true,}
  ],

  "legends": [
    {
      "stroke": "color",
      "symbolType": "circle",
      "title": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "symbols": {
          "update": {
            "fill": {
              "value": "transparent"
            },
            "opacity": {
              "value": 0.7
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "series",
          "data": "stocks",
          "groupby": "symbol"
        }
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}},
          "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "clip": true,
          "from": {"data": "series"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "x": {
                "scale": "xscale",
                "field": "date",
                "offset": {
                  "scale": "xOffset",
                  "field": "symbol"
                }
              },
              "width": {
                "signal": "bandwidth('xOffset')"
              },
              "y": {
                "scale": "yscale",
                "value": 0
              },
              "y2": {
                "scale": "yscale",
                "field":"price"
              },
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "symbol"},
            }
          },
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

So to sum up, I want to achieve the following things:

1. for xOffset，step in range is quite tricky to set, is there a way to set it according to the number of data?
2. the bar width stays the same when zoomed in, is it possible to enlarge the barwidth with zooming?